# Python writing data to json error: "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null"

Tags: python, json

This is a test program I'm using to try appending lists to a json file. The actual main program will continuously append the same list with different values to its json file. Here I'm testing it by trying to append 5 instances of a list. I keep getting the error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null" when trying to run it.

I've tried using `print(mapping)` to see where it fails and it never executed that command. I'm unsure if it's just my code or something else but the program doesn't run at all. I get "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null" when using VSCode's debugger and the program seems to freeze entirely with no output when run from a terminal.

```
import json as js
import numpy as np
from os import time

resolution = 200 # Map resolution: Max = 200
step = [None for _ in range(resolution)] # Angle/Step list
dist = [None for _ in range(resolution)] # Distance list
mapping = [step, dist] # Mapping distances do steps/angles

print(mapping)

with open("test.json", "a") as test:
    ps.dumps(os.time(), test)
    for turn in range(5):
        for num in range(resolution):
            step[num] = num
            dist[num] = np.random()
            js.dumps(mapping, test)
```

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a very python-y error message. Please post the full error with as much context as possible, perhaps a screenshot.

Comment: This actually sounds like you ran this code as JavaScript. It is typical JavaScript error message.

Comment: This is a .py file. The only thing js-y thing here is using json. Also, I got nothing besides what I've already uploaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you declare a variable outside, it doesn't change as it's contents do. Try putting the `mapping` declaration inside the loop and see what happens.

Alternatively do

```py
js.dump(list(step[num], dist[num]), test)
```

Edit: It seems i was wrong about this. I tested it now and got something that works in python3:

```py
import json
import numpy
resolution = 200 # Map resolution: Max = 200
step = [None for _ in range(resolution)] # Angle/Step list
dist = [None for _ in range(resolution)] # Distance list
mapping = list()

with open("test.json", "a") as test:
    for turn in range(5):
        for num in range(resolution):
            step[num] = num
            dist[num] = numpy.random.random()
        mapping = [step, dist]
        json.dump(mapping, test)
        test.write(',\n')
```

Things to note:

```
1. json.dump instead of json.dumps for writing into file
2. declared mapping as an empty list that gets declared after the loop
3. also write a ',\n' to the json file to make it more readable
```

I'll try to help as much as i can in the comments as well, sorry for the initial weak answer.

Comment: Putting ```global step, dist, mapping```  inside ```for num in range(resolution):``` helped get rid of the previous error but now I'm getting different errors: 
```name 'step' is assigned to before global declaration Python(parser-16)```
```name 'dist' is assigned to before global declaration Python(parser-16)```
```name 'mapping' is assigned to before global declaration Python(parser-16)```. 
I'd like to have those pre-declared variables initiated at the start, however, so I'd rather not just move them all inside.

Comment: Declaring as global doesn't change much here.. If you really need the mapping variable declared first I suggest declaring it as ```mapping = list()``` first,  then AFTER the loop is done and all members of ```step``` and ```dist``` have been determined, assign it's values ```mapping = [step, dist]```

Comment: I've tried not declaring step, dist and mapping beforehand, only declaring them inside ```for num in range(resolution):``` and it managed to run but nothing was written to test.json. I've also tried using ```"w"``` instead of ```"a"``` but nothing got written in either case.

Comment: Check the edit, i hope it's somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thank you. That pretty much solved my problem. Turns out changing ```js.dumps``` to ```js.dump``` was the solution to it.